# Angular UI-Router ui-view in ui-view

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have `ui-view` in index.html and I have a page for info and there I want to put second ui-view with 4 links.

In my index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

This is my info. I want to open default in info.html a page info-number.html.

```
<div class="col-sm-8" style="border:1px solid; min-height:
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <div ui-sref></div>
</div>
```

This is my app.

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "home.html"
    })
    .state("info", {
        url: "/info",
        templateUrl: "info.html",
    })
    .state("info-number", {
        abstract: true,
        parent: "info",
        url: "/info-number",
        templateUrl: "info-number.html"
    })
    .state("info-about", {
        parent: "info",
        url: "/info-about",
        templateUrl: "info-about.html"
    })
    .state("info-where", {
        parent: "info",
        url: "/info-where",
        templateUrl: "info-where.html"
    })
  }
]);
```

Schema of my page for info

[image: Schema of my page for info]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need put `info-number` to be `abstract` even if its default.

Your `abstract` view should be `info`. So when user clicks on "info" link (button) you can just redirect him to `info/info-number` as default.

I would write it as:

```
$stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "home.html"
        })
        .state("info", {
            url: "/info",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "info.html",
        })
        .state("info.info-number", {
            url: "/info-number",
            templateUrl: "info-number.html"
        })
        .state("info.info-about", {                
            url: "/info-about",
            templateUrl: "info-about.html"
        })
        .state("info.info-where", {               
            url: "/info-where",
            templateUrl: "info-where.html"
        })
```

The `info.html` has structure similar to:

```
<div>
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```